# JPA find method persists data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using spring jpa. I have implemented transaction management using

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'find' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>    

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="transactionalServiceOperation"
        expression="execution(* com.test..*ServiceImpl.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionalServiceOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

Recently i noticed that although in some cases transaction management is working but in other cases it is not. For example , i have this piece of code inside a service method which is annotated by `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.
 The code inside the method

```
guardianService.save(newFather);
parentsSet.add(newFather);
Guardian oldMother = guardianService.findById(motherId);
```

In the above case the data in the database does not persis till the 3rd line. As soon as the application finishes executing the 3rd line the data of newFather gets comited to the database even if the application generates Exception after the 3rd line.

Code snippet of   `guardianService.findById(motherId)`

```
@Override
public Guardian findById(long guardianId) {
    return guardianRepository.findByGuardianId(guardianId);
}
```

Inside GuardianRepository

```
public interface GuardianRepository extends JpaRepository<Guardian, Long> {

Guardian findByGuardianId(long id);
}
```

Code snippet of `guardianService.save(newFather);`

```
@Override
@Transactional 
public Guardian save(Guardian guardian) {
    return guardianRepository.save(guardian);
}
```

So my question is does the `find()` method somehow calls the `flush()` or `commit()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `find()` method actually does invoke the `flush` method. By default in JPA, [FlushModeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html) is set to [AUTO](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html#AUTO), which means that if query to database occurs, the data in database has to be up to date for current transaction. From definition:

> When queries are executed within a transaction, if FlushModeType.AUTO
>   is set on the Query object, or if the flush mode setting for the
>   persistence context is AUTO (the default) and a flush mode setting has
>   not been specified for the Query object, the persistence provider is
>   responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities
>   in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result
>   of the query are visible to the processing of the query.